# openssl p12 generation failing with CA bundle chain option

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, openssl

I'm trying to install an SSL certificate for a Java servlet framework. I have 3 files: the private key (PEM), certificate file (PEM) and CA bundle (PEM). When I run:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key -certfile server.crt -out server.p12 -CAfile server.ca-bundle -chain
```

...in order to get the `p12` file that I can use to create the Java keystore, it fails with the following error:

```
Error unable to get issuer certificate getting chain.
```

Elsewhere, I have successfully setup 2 apache servers using the same key, certificate and CA bundle files and there are no problems. Why might I be getting this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found (the|a) solution to this problem on [this blog post](http://www.fourproc.com/2010/06/23/create-a-ssl-keystore-for-a-tomcat-server-using-openssl-.html). From the post:

> After a bit of testing, I found that you need to make a new CAfile to be used, that combines the cacerts file from the openssl distribution and the intermediate.crt file...

...which is:

```
cat your-server-bundle /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt > allcacerts.crt
```

...then use `allcacerts.crt` (or whatever you call it) as the parameter to the `-CAfile` option in the openssl command.